# How to simplify $\sum\limits_{n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_d=n}(n!/n_1!n_2!\cdots n_d!)^2$?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, combinations

How to simplify $\sum\limits_{n_1+n_2+\ldots+n_d=n}(n!/n_1!n_2!\cdots n_d!)^2$?

I already know that when $d=2$ it equals $\binom{2n}{n}$. But I do not know how to simplify it when $d \geq 3$.

Note that $n,n_1,\ldots,n_d \in \mathbb N^+$.

Comment: See here https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407327